# Is it possible to make key words in python

Tags: python, keyword

I was wondering if it was possible to make a keyword similar to 'and', or if it is part of the python compiler?
Thx

Comment: You could contribute to the PSF and suggest one

Comment: Does filing a PEP/ editing cpython count?  But more generally, what do you want to do?

Comment: Short answer: no. Python doesn't support macros, like other languages that allow you to extend their syntax.

Comment: Keywords are typically part of the grammar, and so "above" what you can define using the language itself. That said, the parser (as of 3.10?) can use context to decide if a word is a keyword or an identifier, which is why the `match` statement could be added without invalidating code that uses `match` as an identifier. (*You* can't make your own keywords, but the grammar can be extended without breaking existing code.)

Answer (score 1):

You can file a PEP (although good luck getting your new keyword accepted); or you can implement it yourself.  Other than that, no: python doesn't allow dynamic syntax.

What you *can* do is look at the magic methods which are called by operators.  Redefining these is sometimes handy.  Pathlib makes it possible to do this:

```
from pathlib import Path 
Path("a/b") / "c/d.txt"
```

And they didn't have to introduce any new operators or keywords,  even though the usual meaning of `/` is division, not concatenation.