# How do I define a keyword in Python to make the command shorter?

Tags: python

I would like to call a function in Python like a keyword. For motivation I have following problem:

Multiple variables can be deleted at once by using the keyword `del`.

```
x1,x2=1,1
del x1,x2
```

However,

```
x1,x2=1,1
del x1,x2,x3
```

leads to a *name error* if `x3` is not defined. The convenience function `Del` deletes multiple variables independently of their existence (see this [SE post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75271379/12842085)):

```
def Del(*d:list[str])->None:
  for i in d:globals().pop(i,None)
```

I can now call

```
x1,x2=1,1
Del('x1','x2','x3')
```

without getting an error message about non-existence of `x3`. However, for my new command `Del` I have to use brackets and quotes whereas for `del` I don't need them. The reason is that `Del` is a function, whereas `del` is a keyword.

How could I define `Del` as a keyword to call it like `Del x1,x2,x3`? Of course, any other method that saves quotes or brackets is welcome.

Comment: You would need to amend the CPython source code to do this.

Comment: `del` is not a keyword, it's a statement.

Comment: I've been writing python code for quite a long time without ever needing to reach for `del`. Are you sure you shouldn't be using a list or dictionary instead? I know that's not what you are asking, but usually when you are trying to do something the language doesn't seem to allow, there is a different, more idiomatic way forward.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70226005/5320906)

Comment: @YuriGinsburg: Well, it's both. It's a reserved keyword that is used as part of the associated statement.

Comment: @Mark: There are legitimate reasons to use `del` for removing elements by index or key from mutable sequences/mappings (and *much* rarer cases for removing attributes of an instance). But yeah, if you find yourself using it to delete plain names, you're usually doing the wrong thing (e.g. in this case, running code in global scope instead of wrapping in a function; it's slower in global scope, it does weird stuff with the scope of the actual functions, and it has the clean-up issues the OP seems to be having).

Comment: @Yuri Ginsburg
 [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=keywords#keywords) is keyword used to make [statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=del#grammar-token-python-grammar-del_stmt)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot extend the grammar of Python via Python code.

Python is a mix between an interpreted and compiled language. This means that a process or program must convert the source code into another form before it can be executed. It is this process that ultimately understands the grammar that makes up Python (including all of the keywords, statements, and other syntax).

In order to extend or change the grammar, you need to change/modify the source code of that process. This is possible, but is not something that would be easy to do (you would have to modify the C code from which the Python binary is built). Additionally, even if you were successful, you could only use the new grammar for programs run using your custom binary. Anyone else running your code would receive syntax errors.